# Coudn't connect to online database in Android app

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to connect my app to online database, i have all the php files working, but my app don't connect to the database. I have to do simple data insertion and data retrieve. I Keep getting null pointer exception.

### RegOneActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class RegOneActivity extends Activity {



Button okaBtn,regbtn;
EditText phno,password;
String phone,pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg_one);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordedittext);
    okaBtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.okbtn);
    phno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpass1);
    regbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createbtn);
    regbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent in = new Intent(RegOneActivity.this, PasswordActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);  

        }
    });

    okaBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            phone = phno.getText().toString();
            pass = password.getText().toString();
            String method = "login";
            /*RegisterBackgroung backGround = new RegisterBackgroung(getApplicationContext());*/
            RegisterBackgroung backGround = new RegisterBackgroung(RegOneActivity.this);
            backGround.execute(method, phone, pass);
            Intent in = new Intent(RegOneActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);  
            RegOneActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
  }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reg_one, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
 }
```

### PasswordActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class PasswordActivity extends Activity {



Button btn;
EditText password1,password2,phone;
String pass1,pass2,phonenumber;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_password);

    btn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.proceed1act);
    password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpass1);
    phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneedt);
    password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpass2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            pass1 = password1.getText().toString();
            pass2 = password2.getText().toString();
            phonenumber = phone.getText().toString();
            String method= "register";
            RegisterBackgroung backtask = new RegisterBackgroung(PasswordActivity.this);
            backtask.execute(method,phonenumber,pass1);

            Intent in = new Intent(PasswordActivity.this, RegOneActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
            PasswordActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.password, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

RegisterBackground.java

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegisterBackgroung  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

Context ctx;
AlertDialog diag;
SharedPreferences sp;
Editor edt;
public RegisterBackgroung(Context ctx) {

    this.ctx = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String urlregister = "http://www.locationsharing.16mb.com/register.php";

    String login = "http://www.locationsharing.16mb.com/retrieve.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if(method.equals("register"))
    {
    String phone = params[1];
    String pass = params[2];

    try {
        URL reg_url = new URL(urlregister);
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) reg_url.openConnection();
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("phonenumber", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8")+"&"+ 
                URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();

        InputStream is = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
        is.close();
        return "Registration Successful!";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }

    else if(method.equals("login")){

        String phone = params[1];
        String pass = params[2];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(login);
            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("phonenumber", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8")+"&"+ 
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
              bw.write(data);
              bw.flush();
              bw.close();
              os.close();


              InputStream is = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"));
              String response = "";
              String line = "";

              while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
              {
                  response += line;  
              }
              br.close();
              is.close();
              httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
              return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    diag.setTitle("Login Information");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result.equals("Registration Successful!"))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {

        diag.setMessage(result);
        diag.show();
    }
  }


 }
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lavisor.locationsharing2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />


 <permission
    android:name="com.testing.svma.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.testing.svma.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegOneActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reg_one" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_password" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PassActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pass" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectCircleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_select_circle" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShareLocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_share_location" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FavouritesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_favourites" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>

     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAZx8eHxiQ5ZRgsDstuyseUKQ_PaH8rlps" />
     <meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the response code you get back when after connecting to the server for httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode(). If I were you I will first  develop simple program to get the connection to server working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to override OnProgressUpdate in the Async task :P and Now, it works perfectly..